# returning DOM element objects as a string?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm not sure how to phrase my question, so I'll just post my code and explain what I'm trying to do:

```
function getNewElement(tagName, className, idName, text){
    var newElement = document.createElement(tagName);
    newElement.className = className;
    newElement.id = idName;
    newElement.innerHTML = text;

    return newElement;
}
```

If I call

```
getNewElement("div", "meow", "meow1", getNewElement("span","meow", "meow2", "blahblahblah"));
```

I just get

```
<div id="meow1" class="meow">[object HTMLSpanElement]</div>
```

So my question is, how would I write this to return a string with out converting (potentially expensive operation?) or ghetto patching with strings.

Update:
ghetto patch version:

```
function getNewElement(tagName, className, idName, text){
    return '<' + tagName + ' class=' + className + ' id=' + idName + '>' + text + '</' + tagName + '>';     
}
```

Achieves the functionality I wanted, but I feel like it's not that elegant.

Comment: I think you need to say if you really want a `HTMLElement` as result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but if you want the contents of `#meow2` in the new element `#meow1`, using the statement as you do, this would be a solution:

```
function getNewElement(tagName, className, idName, contents){
    var newElement = document.createElement(tagName);
    newElement.className = className;
    newElement.id = idName;
    newElement.innerHTML = 
          typeof contents === 'string' ? contents : contents.innerHTML;
    return newElement;
}
```

now

```
getNewElement("div", "meow", "meow1", 
              getNewElement("span","meow", "meow2", "blahblahblah"));
```

would create a new element `#meow1`, with the content of a newly created element `#meow2`. Appended somewhere in the document it would look like:

```
<div class="meow" id="meow1">blahblahblah</div>
```

Otherwise, if you want `#meow2` to be a child of `#meow1`, this would be a solution:

```
function getNewElement(tagName, className, idName, contents){
    var newElement = document.createElement(tagName);
    newElement.className = className;
    newElement.id = idName;
    if (typeof contents === 'string'){
      newElement.innerHTML = contents;
    } else {
      newElement.appendChild(contents);
    }
    return newElement;
}
```

Now if you would do:

```
document.body.appendChild(
     getNewElement("div", "meow", "meow1", 
                   getNewElement("span","meow", "meow2", "blahblahblah"))
);
```

this would be the result:

```
 <div class="meow" id="meow1">
  <span class="meow" id="meow2">blahblahblah</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Similar to above solution, but with more details! Thanks!

Comment: And to specify, I did want #meow2 to be the child of #meow1

Comment: Also to ask, is there any performance disadvantage to my ghetto patched solution in my update compared to this one?

Comment: Your patch creates a string, you still have to use `innerHTML` in some  element to add it to the DOM. So it won't create an element in the DOM. Generally, `innerHTML`s performance shouldn't differ much from using DOM methods - see http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/innerhtml/
BTW, what do you mean with 'ghetto patch'?

Comment: I say ghetto patch as in just somewhat poorly hacked together to achieve some effect, not really the most elegant solution. And thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `innerHTML`, try `appendChild`.

newElement.appendChild(text);

EDIT: Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
if(text instanceOf Object) {
    newElement.appendChild(text);
} else {
    newElement.createTextNode(text);
}
```

Comment: appendChild() would require document.createTextNode(), which gives me the same result.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding your requirement correctly. I made an edit to my answer, is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to take multiple type in parameter `text`

```
function getNewElement(tagName, className, idName, text){
    var newElement = document.createElement(tagName);
    newElement.className = className;
    newElement.id = idName;
    newElement.innerHTML = 
          typeof text === 'string' ? text: text.outerHTML;
    return newElement;
}
```